# I believe that the variance in my mixed model is too low

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model

I have a dataset of 605 observations consisting of NBA players divided into 30 teams. I have estimated the points scored (PTS) by each player using a linear regression model with other numeric variables. I have applied a square root transformation to the response variable (Y). Now, I want to fit a mixed model based on the teams. Upon observing the output of the model (where Y represents my transformed response variable), I realize that the variance is very low. Does this mean that my model is not good?

```r
modello_random <- lmer(PTS_transformed ~ . + (1 | Team), 
                       data = dati_filtrati[, -c(2,16,4,8,9,13)])
```

I have no idea sinc.

Comment: Why are you transforming points? Better to use a model that fits the data. 
What is the subsetting you are doing? Looks like you are removing some data, which might be OK, but why? Are you doing lmer on all the variables except those? How many variables are you using? Why did you remove those?
And remember that the variance will now be in square root of points units. That will shrink it a lot.

Comment: Square root transformation compress pdf distributions which, by definition, reduces variance. What do you mean by "observing the output"? In other words, which metrics are you looking at wrt variance? What metrics would you use to define a *good* model? Since your unit of analysis is the player, is your data for one year only? Or is it aggregated across years? if the latter, you might want to consider adding a row for each player-year combination.